How do you get all the running programs and processes currently running in C++ for Windows 11 using the built in libraries like WIndows.h?
Because I want to make a C++ program that displays all your currently running processes and applications but I don't know where to start with this.
I tried to make look for C++ functions that might be related to that but didn't find anything.

Keyword search: win32 get process list. Early result (First for me, but your results may differ): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes I suspect that your application's permissions may not allow you to see the stuff Windows wants to keep hidden, but it's a great place to start.

The C++ standard library doesn't have anything to do this. Windows probably does, which is why @user4581301 pointed you to the Windows documentation.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

C++ has no concept of processes. But the OS does. See MSDN documentation: Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes and Enumerating All Processes

In Windows, there's a difference between processes and applications (Processes and Threads)
If you want to work with win processes in C++, you can use functions from the Process Status API (PSAPI), which is included in the psapi.h header

EnumProcesses: Enumerates all process IDs
EnumProcesses(processes, sizeof(processes), &cbNeeded);


EnumProcessModulesEx: Enumerates the modules within a process
EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeededModule, LIST_MODULES_ALL);


GetModuleBaseNameA: Retrieves the name of the module (often the executable name)
GetModuleBaseNameA(hProcess, hMod, processName, sizeof(processName) / sizeof(char));



MSDN example
example
